# Delphi Write TResourceStream into TStream

Tags: delphi, stream

I have embedded an exe file in Resorce file.
when I just Use Stream.SaveToFile('test.exe'); everything works fine,produced  exe file works with no error. but when i try to  Stream.SaveToStream(Stin); , I get error " Stream write error " . what's wrong with my code ?

```
var
list: TStringList;
Stream: TResourceStream;
Stin, Stout: TStream;
MemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'phprogram' , RT_RCDATA);
try

  Stin := TStream.Create;
  Stout := TStream.Create;
  Stream.Position := 0;
  Stream.SaveToStream(Stin);
  EnDecryptStream(Stin, Stout, 2913);
  MemStream.LoadFromStream(Stout);
  MemStream.SaveToFile('test.exe');
  //Stream.SaveToFile('test.exe');

 finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
end;
```

**Edited :**

Thanks to David ... I changed my code and it worked fine :

```
var

  Stream: TResourceStream;
 MemStream: TMemoryStream;
 begin
   Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'testres' , RT_RCDATA);
   MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try

     EnDecryptStream(Stream, MemStream, 2913);
     MemStream.SaveToFile('test.exe');

   finally
   MemStream.Free;
  Stream.Free;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TStream` is an abstract class. You must not instantiate instances of `TStream`. You must always instantiate a concrete class derived from `TStream`, such as `TFileStream`, `TMemoryStream`, `TStringStream`, etc.

Furthermore, you use `MemStream` without initialising it.

It looks like you need to do something like this:

- Create the resource stream.
- Create a memory stream.
- Call `EnDecryptStream` providing the resource stream as input and the memory stream as output.
- Call `SaveToFile` on the memory stream to save it.

Or even simpler:

- Create the resource stream.
- Create a file stream.
- Call `EnDecryptStream` providing the resource stream as input and the file stream as output.

One of the most common anti-patterns that we see on Stack Overflow is the excessive use of the memory stream. You appear to want to write to a file, so why not cut out the memory stream, and go straight to the file.

I don't particularly want to write any code here because we can only see a small part of the picture here, and any code that I would write would likely be wrong.

I suspect that you have not enabled compiler warnings and hints, or are perhaps ignoring them. Don't do that. Enable warnings and hints, and heed them.